# "елочка" все коментит, там где должен быть код

Tags: php, html, sql, phpstorm

Может и банальщина и ответ очевиден, ноо... Почему-то после символа ">" все комментируется и там где должен быть исполнен код, просто выводит текст. Возможно ответ банален и на поверхности, но я уже голову сломал, гляньте как исправить ситуацию. Это один из примеров кода, со всеми утыкание в том же месте.
Использую PhpStorm, в NetBeans такая же шляпа.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "Egor";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "egor";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn-> connect_error)
{
die("Connection failed: " . $conn-> connect_error);
}
$result = $mysqli-> query("Select * From Avto");
while($rows = $result -> fetch_assoc());
{
print '$rows["Avto_hoster"]';
}
?>

</table>

</body>
</html
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вебсервер есть?

Comment: Да, тот же код но в php-файле замечательно работает на сервере(http://localhost:81/test/sql.php), но как только я размещаю его в html начинаются танцы...

Comment: Ну так не размещай в .html-файле. Или директиву вебсерверу пропиши, чтоб он обрабатывал .html как .php, но это крайний случай.

Answer (score 1):

Короче все решилось, использовал расширение вместо HTML php, но с конструкцией HTML внутри. Все работает. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Очень советую пользоваться IDE с подсветкой и статическим анализом.

[image: Скриншот IDE].

1. Лишние пробелы при обращение к свойствам и методам объекта. Должно быть

   ```
    $conn->connect_error
    $result->fetch_accsoc()
   ```
2. Переменная `$mysqli` не определена.
3. Лишняя точка с запятой после условия в `while`.
4. Закрывающий `html` также с ошибкой.

Comment: Ваши замечания исправил.Спасибо, но к сожалению ситуация та же.

Comment: @HappyHends ваша проблема в том, что файл читается как обычный html, я уверен что вы больше чем напортачили..